# VBA button copying from one sheet to another with his private Subs

Tags: vba, excel

Maybe there is a question like this but i couldnt find it and i dont have much time. I'm sorry if i reapeat someone's question.

So i have a button in my "Sheet1". This button has a Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() -->

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

I want to copy the button into Sheet2 (this sheet already exist) into a a cell of my choise (for example B5) and the button to has the same Sub as the original one so to can open the UserForm1 when i click it.

Answer (score 0):

to simply copy and paste buttons all over the workbook sheets and having them always run the same macro you have to assign the button a macro qualifying the module name it resides in also

for instance should your `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` reside in Module1 then you:

- right-click the button
- choose "assign macro" (or the likes - I don't have English UI)
- in the "Macro name" textbox type in:

  `Module1.CommandButton1_Click`
- press "OK"

now you can copy the button in any other sheet